# Angular 7 - compilation error in Prod built - ERROR in : Error: Internal error: unknown identifier undefined

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular7, aot

i have been trying to build the angular 7 app in prod mode using the npm command ng build --configuration=prod and generating the error. While running with ng build everything is fine.

I do not see anything specific about the components\services that we have written. Here is the copy of the error message. Is there a way to get the real message or if anything obvious that i'm missing.

```
ERROR in : Error: Internal error: unknown identifier undefined
    at Object.importExpr$$1 [as importExpr] (C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24170:27)
    at tokenExpr (C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:19863:43)
    at providerDef (C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:19789:24)
    at C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:19959:81
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at NgModuleCompiler.compile (C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:19959:48)
    at AotCompiler._compileModule (C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24115:36)
    at C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24034:70
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler._compileImplFile (C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24034:23)
    at C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24024:74
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler.emitAllImpls (C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24024:39)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.generateFilesForEmit (C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:620:46)
    at AngularCompilerProgram._emitRender2 (C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:266:47)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.emit (C:\ui\TestOptimization.UI\client\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\transformers\program.js:201:22)
```